# Applescript automate double keystroke

Tags: applescript

I need to emulate a keystroke using applescript for double time shift press.

Adding Part of snippet..

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke shift
    keystroke shift
end tell
```

Even tried

```
keystroke shift
delay 0.1
keystroke shift
```

still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the app you are trying to target with this double shift effect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `key down` followed by `key up`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down shift
    key up shift
    key down shift
    key up shift
end tell
```